# How to add elements to an already created JList (Netbeans generated)

Tags: java, swing, oop, netbeans, jlist

I am developing an application in Netbeans using Java and have been told to use the GUI creation features that Netbeans offer. Due to this I cannot edit the initComponents(); method to edit the creation of the JList and add a default list model to it.

I have tried creating a new JList but that resulted in an infinite loop. I haven't ever created controls through coding them myself, only by an IDE's GUI creation tools.

This is what I have currently:

```
private void formWindowActivated(java.awt.event.WindowEvent evt) {                                     
    //String to hold current patients data
    String patientDetails;

    //Take the arraylist from the model
    ArrayList<IAccountStrategy> unapprovedPatients;
    unapprovedPatients = model.getObservers();

    //Create default list model to store the patients details
    DefaultListModel<String> unapprovedPatientModel = new DefaultListModel<>();

    IAccountStrategy xx;

    //For loop to iterate through each element of unapprovedPatients
    for(int i = 0; i < unapprovedPatients.size(); i++){

        //get the current patients details and store them in a string variable
        xx = unapprovedPatients.get(i);
        patientDetails = xx.getAccountID() + xx.getUsername() + xx.getFirstname() + xx.getLastname();

        //Add string variable to list model
        unapprovedPatientModel.addElement(patientDetails);
    }
    //add list model to existing JList
    listPatients.addElement(unapprovedPatientModel);
}
```

I would like to output all the elements from the list model into the actual JList and then let the user interact with the list itself.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: *"I cannot edit the initComponents(); method"* That's the first thing you should fix. You're not using the IDE, it is using you.

Comment: Yeah my lecturer has specified that we use the GUI in this way, is it not possible to use the list as I want if I am using the IDE this way?

Comment: *"..is it not possible to use the list as I want if I am using the IDE this way?"* Sure it's possible. You are currently being hobbled by using the GUI designer. It makes some things easier, but other things (like this) harder. Also, your instructor is an idiot for teaching 'an IDE' rather than Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is it not possible to use the list as I want

You just wrote code to create the DefaultListModel.

So now all you need is to add:

```
list.setModel( unapprovedPatientModel );
```

so the JList can use the newly created model.

Although the problem with this code is that the code will be executed every time the window is activated.

But the point is that all you need to do is update the list using the setModel() method. How you do this in the IDE is up to you.